# How to modify the ratio of profiles photos in UltimateMembers for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, size, photo, ultimate-member

I'm using Ultimate Members on my WP Website. The profile photos and galleries photos are squared. I'd like to display them on 4:3. I would also like to change the number of profiles per row in the grid gallery members ( 3 profiles per row ).